# VBA Excel Xlookup refer to table column

Tags: excel, vba, tablecolumn, xlookup

I have a code for my ComboBox2 which works properly. Now I want to change values in combobox2 and based on that in the textbox6 get a number which is in a column (Total) which is the 6th column of the table (Table1) in another sheet (sheet2).

```
Private Sub combobox2_Change()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range

   
Set tbl = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")

Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange

Me.TextBox6.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Me.ComboBox2.Value, Sheets("sheet2").Range("A2:A7"), Sheets("sheet2").Rng)

End Sub
```

Could you please tell me why my code does not work? Thanks

I tried the code but I dont now how to get the third variable in the XLOOKUP correct.

Comment: What is in `Sheets("sheet2").Range("A2:A7")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to lookup the combobox value in the 1st table column and return the value in the 6th.

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
        Set rng = .ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
        Me.TextBox6.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup _
              (Me.ComboBox2.Value, rng.Columns(1), rng.Columns(6))
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, my almost identical answer coincided with yours; I'm free to delete mine as you posted yours before. @CDP1802

Comment: @T.M. Wait till op responds, we might both be wrong :)

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted and by range A2:A7 I did want to refer to column 1 of the same table. So, right on the target! Many thanks

Comment: Both were right, upvtd :+)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that there is no `Sheets("sheet2").Rng` object, variable `rng` would suffice as 3rd argument in your `XLookUp` function.

Assuming range `A2:A7` is part of your listobject, you might code as follows.

```
Private Sub combobox2_Change()

'a) reference Listobject in Sheet2
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = Sheet2.ListObjects("Table1")          ' referencing the worksheet's Code(Name) Sheet2
'b) reference listobject data ranges
    Dim lookupRng As Range
    Set lookupRng = tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange    ' or: identify column by its name string in bracket
    Dim returnRng As Range
    Set returnRng = tbl.ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange    ' or: identify column by its name string in bracket
'c) get result providing for non-finding
    Dim result
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Me.ComboBox2.value, lookupRng, returnRng, "")
'd) write result
    If result <> vbNullString Then
        Me.TextBox6.value = result
    End If

End Sub
```

**[Help reference `XLookUp` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not test the code, as the code in first answer solved my problem but I also understood from your answer and instructions what my problem was. 
Many thanks for your time

Comment: @shahinsyr You are welcome. This code suggestion isn't so far from yours, I just declared *two* range variables instead of your `rng` (which references only the 6th listbox column) and integrated these variables as arguments into the function call. The condition check only tests if the returned value is no empty string (see last function argument "" chosen here for non-findings). Furthermore I referenced the Listobject residing in worksheet "Sheet2" here by its Code(Name), other ways are to write e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")` :-)